# Default pagination is broken when use 'static page' as 'front page'

Tags: pagination

currently I have installed wordpress v4.7.2 and created a child-theme by **twentyfifteen**

I have create a **custom post type**.

[image]

now when browse the **localhost**, I got as should be the list, and the pagination is not working :( :

for example for page2 points

> localhost/page/2/

--

when accessing as **localhost/works**

the pagination working fine 
[image]

the code Im using also on **archive** and **template** files, is the following :

```
// Previous/next page navigation.
the_posts_pagination( array(
    'prev_text'          => __( 'Previous page', 'twentyfifteen' ),
    'next_text'          => __( 'Next page', 'twentyfifteen' ),
    'before_page_number' => '<span class="meta-nav screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Page', 'twentyfifteen' ) . ' </span>',
) );

<!--when WORKS is as default page homepage-->
works-template.php

<!--when access it via localhost/works-->
archive-works.php
```

the only different is that on **works-template.php**, calling the **query_posts()**

```
<?php
$posts_per_page = get_query_var('posts_per_page');
$paged          = ( get_query_var('page') ) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
$args           = array('post_type'     => 'works','posts_per_page'=> $posts_per_page ,'post_status'   => 'publish' ,'orderby'       => 'menu_order','order'         => 'ASC','paged'         =>$paged);


query_posts( $args );

// Start the Loop.
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
```

any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

the solution is dont use #static pages# and merge to **functions.php**

Merge to functions.php the following :

```
//http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/02/02/showing-custom-post-types-on-your-home-blog-page
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_get_posts' );

function my_get_posts( $query ) {

    if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() )
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'works' ) );
    //else 
        //$query->set( 'post_type', ' page' );//$query->set( 'post_type', array( 'page', 'post' ) );

    return $query;
}
```